# Alias/Rename a command in Tcl but keep both versions working

Tags: tcl

My goal is to alias/rename **proc** to **func** but keep both versions working.
That's why the tcl's built-in **rename** command is not an options because when I

```
rename proc func
```

**proc** stops working. And when **proc** does't work built-in commands like  **tk_getOpenFile** does't work.

Possible solution would be to build a wrapper like this

```
proc func { arg } {
  proc $arg
}
```

The above does't work because I'm a beginner and I don't know what I'm doing but in theory a wrapper should be a valid solution.
Also when I learn how to do the aforementioned I will also try to rename **puts** to **print** and keep both versions working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an interpreter alias:

```
interp alias {} func {} proc
```

Documentation:
[interp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/interp.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are the usual answer. However, in Tcl 8.6 you can also use `tailcall`:

```
proc func {name arguments body} {
    tailcall proc $name $arguments $body
}
```

Prior to that, the right invokation would be this (given that `proc` always returns the empty string):

```
proc func {name arguments body} {
    uplevel 1 [list proc $name $arguments $body]
}
```

Why the `uplevel`? Because it matters what the current namespace is when `name` does not refer to a fully-qualified name; doing the evaluation in the *caller's* context makes things “non-surprising”. (The version with `tailcall` also handles this right.)

---

For all that, I actually prefer to define `func` like this in my programs:

```
proc func {name arguments body} {
    tailcall proc tcl::mathfunc::$name $arguments [list expr $body]
}
```

Why? Because then this “just works”:

```
func cube x {
    $x ** 3
}

set num [expr { cube(17) }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the In-depth explanation and examples, awesome job!